# Faking/setting the Tomcat context path

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

We run about 30 webapps on various Tomcat instances behind load balancers and Apache reverse proxies using mod_jk.  The public URL of each application is configured into the Apache mod_jk config which proxies to the backend Tomcats.  The backend Tomcat runs the application on a context path which matches the public URL.

e.g.

```
domain.com/foo/bar/webapp -- mod_jk --> tomcat/foo/bar/webapp
```

This is because the applications build links in the JSPs using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`, e.g.

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/image-manipulation.js" >     </script>
```

I'd like to make this more loosly coupled, and "containerise" the webapps, so they each run in their own Tomcat container, on the default context, i.e. `/` without needing to know what their public URL is.  This would simplify managing the Tomcat configuration and mod_jk mappings.

The problem is how can the application build absolute links to within itself, without knowing what it's final public URL is?  Is there a way to pass the URL in the mod_jk request, and have Tomcat override calls to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` with this URL?

Or is it better to use something like `mod_substitute` in Apache to replace a fixed string in the page with the URL when it's heading out of Apache?  This seems inefficient as Apache has to then scan all the pages doing this find & replace..

Or is it best just to leave it all as it is, and use the context path as currently?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of would be something like:

- configuring mod_jk to send the wanted `contextPath` as a variable through `JkEnvVar` (will be available in tomcat as a request param)
- have a filter in your webapp wrapping the request and using that variable to override `getContextPath()`
- wrap your response too to handle `sendRedirect()` and other similar methods correctly (might not be that easy).

Of course, if tomcat could do all of that for you...